# XSL Transform to generate output XML dynamically from properties of the input

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Apologies in advance for the length of this, there's just a few important details to fully elaborate the problem I'm having, but this (should be!) is a simple XSLT question at its heart.

---

I have the following 3 XML documents (to serve as examples of their structure):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rabbitEnvelope>
    <action>YES</action>
    <logId>123</logId>
    <payload class="rabbit">
            <id>1</id>
            <name>Some Bunny</name>
            <easter>false</easter>
    </payload>
</rabbitEnvelope>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<bearEnvelope>
    <action>NO</action>
    <logId>456</logId>
    <payload class="bear">
            <type>Polar</type>
            <weight>655</weight>
    </payload>
</bearEnvelope>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dogEnvelope>
    <action>MAYBE</action>
    <logId>789</logId>
    <payload class="dog">
            <goodboy>YES!</goodboy>
            <eats>Everything</eats>
        <canFetch>true</canFetch>
        <moniker>Fido</moniker>
    </payload>
</dogEnvelope>
```

We'll call these the "*classic versions*" of these 3 different XML documents.

My app will now be receiving "*new versions*" of them, and I need to write an XSL transform to transform the new versions into the classic ones. The new versions (again just as examples) of these XML documents will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<envelope>
    <action>YES</action>
    <auditId>123</auditId>
    <payload class="rabbit">
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Some Bunny</name>
        <easter>false</easter>
    </payload>
</envelope>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<envelope>
    <action>NO</action>
    <auditId>456</auditId>
    <payload class="bear">
        <type>Polar</type>
        <weight>655</weight>
    </payload>
</envelope>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<envelope>
    <action>MAYBE</action>
    <auditId>789</auditId>
    <payload class="dog">
        <goodboy>YES!</goodboy>
        <eats>Everything</eats>
        <canFetch>true</canFetch>
        <moniker>Fido</moniker>
    </payload>
</envelope>
```

So, in these "new versions", the outer-most XML element will *always* be an `<envelope>` element. The `<action>` element is the same for the new version as it is in the classic version. The new `/envelope/auditId` is the same as the classic version's `<logId>` (`/rabbitEnvelope/logId`, etc.). And `/envelope/payload` is also exactly the same is in the classic version (`/bearEnvelope/payload`, etc.).

So again, I need to write an XSL transform that will convert new versions of the XML (`<envelope>` payloads) to its classic version. As a rule:

- The `/envelope/payload/@class` value determines the name of the classic version's outermost element. Hence is `/envelope/payload/@class='rock'`, then its "classic" version's outermost/root element will be `<rockEnvelope>`.
- I want to copy `/envelope/action` to `/<rootElementEnvelope>/action`. Hence if `/envelope/action='YES'` then `/<rootElementEnvelope>/action='YES'`.
- I want to copy the *value* of `/envelope/auditId` to `<rootElementEnvelope>/logId`. Hence if `/envelope/auditId='123'` then `/<rootElementEnvelope>/logId='123'`.
- I want to copy the **entire** `/envelope/payload` to `/<rootElementEnvelope>/payload`, no changes whatsoever.

My first stab at a generic XSLT looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="//envelope">
    <!-- The rabbitEnvelope element needs to be dynamically generated! -->
    <rabbitEnvelope>
        <action><xsl:value-of select="../action"/></action>
        <logId><xsl:value-of select="../auditId"/></logId>
        <payload class="???">
            <!-- All the XML from inside the source payload tag-->
        </payload>
    </rabbitEnvelope>
</xsl:template>
```

However there are a few issues here due to the same/common dynamic nature of my requirements.

1. Since the `<payload class=???>` value determines whether the transformed/resultant root tag is a `<rabbitEnvelope>`, `<bearEnvelope>`, `<dogEnvelope>`, `<rockEnvelope>` (or any other type, **and there are MANY!**), I can't just hardcode `<rabbitEnvelope>` into my XSLT.
2. I *believe* my use of `<action><xsl:value-of select="../action"/></action>` and `<logId><xsl:value-of select="../auditId"/></logId>` is correct, but if you see something wrong with it, please let me know!
3. I'm not sure how to generate the output/resultant `<payload/>` tag since its just a straight copy from whatever is in the input XML and can't be hardcoded.

**Any ideas how I can accomplish the desired transform given the dynamic nature of my requirements here?** Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 2.0 (also compatible with XSLT 1.0)**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/envelope">
    <xsl:element name="{payload/@class}Envelope">
        <xsl:copy-of select="action"/>
        <logId>
            <xsl:value-of select="auditId"/>
        </logId>
        <xsl:copy-of select="payload"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```